# Trying to use current_user where it is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, undefined

I have this call in my vote model:

```
 fires :vote_updated, :on => :update,
                   :actor => :user,
                   :secondary_subject => :video,
                   :if => lambda { |vote| ((vote.value == 1) || (vote.value == -1)) && (vote.video.user != current_user)}
```

In case you aren't familiar, it works with the [timeline_fu plugin](https://github.com/jamesgolick/timeline_fu).

I do not want the call to be fired if the user who owns the voted up video is the current user. That is where this line comes in:

```
:if => lambda { |vote| ((vote.value == 1) || (vote.value == -1)) && (vote.video.user != current_user)}
```

However, I do not have access to `current_user` here. How do I get around this?

Here's the create method in my votes controller (there actually is no update method):

```
def create       
  @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
  @vote = current_user.video_votes.find_or_create_by_video_id(@video.id)

  if @vote.value.nil?
    if params[:type] == "up"
      @vote.value = 1
    else
      @vote.value = -1
    end
  elsif (params[:type] == "up" && @vote.value == 1) || (params[:type] == "down" && @vote.value == -1)
    @vote.value = 0
  elsif ((params[:type] == "up" && @vote.value == -1) || (params[:type] == "down" && @vote.value == 1)) || (@vote.value == 0)
    if params[:type] == "up"
      @vote.value = 1
    else
      @vote.value = -1
    end
  end  

  if @vote.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @video }
      format.js
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the right thing to do would be validating this in controller. I would create a before filter for this case

UPDATE:

Just as a quick example:

```
before_filter :valid_vote, :only => :update

def update
   @vote.update_attributes(params[:vote]) # or whatever
end
..

private

def valid_vote
   @vote = Vote.find params[:id]
   unless ( @vote.video.user.id != current_user.id )
      render :text => 'You can't vote for your own video', :status => 403
   end
end
```

So @vote is being declared and validated before your 'update' action is proccessed.
If it's not valid then your 'update' action stays untouched

UPDATE 2 :

not sure how you'll like it, but you could also do as follows:

in your Vote model:

```
attr_accessor :skip_timeline
```

then use the concept with before filter, but do `@vote.skip_timeline = true` instead of rendering text

then the statement might look as follows:

```
:if => lambda { |vote| ((vote.value == 1) || (vote.value == -1)) && !vote.skip_timeline }
```

You could also move `((vote.value == 1) || (vote.value == -1))` to your before filter :

```
def valid_vote
   @vote = Vote.find params[:id]
   unless ( [1,-1].include? @vote.value && @vote.video.user.id != current_user.id )
       @vote.skip_timeline = true
   end
end
```

and

:if => lambda { |vote| !vote.skip_timeline }

Comment: which controller? and what would this look like?

Comment: oh i see what you're doing... what I'm asking is different though. It's not so that users can't vote on their own video, but rather that a timeline_event object will not be created for the current_user if he/she is the owner of the video, regardless of who voted up the video.

Comment: thanks... the one problem with this is that if I implement a before filter, then I cannot retrieve the vote because it has not been created yet...

Comment: I changed it to an after_filter but it doesn't seem to work... maybe because the timeline_event object is created before the after_filter is called?

Comment: ah, ok. got confused since there's :on => :update. It's just not 'rails' or even 'mvc' way to use things like current_user in your model, so we're trying to suggest some workarounds. Could you also show your 'update' action and what's the authentication gem you're using?

Comment: yeah, I think :on => update is basically just a before_update callback... any idea on how to work around this last problem?

Comment: I'm just using the built in sessions for authentication, I posted the action above

Comment: ah, ok. then you could just add @vote.skip_timeline = true unless ( [1,-1].include? @vote.value && @vote.video.user.id != current_user.id ) somewhere in your action and there's no need for before filter

Comment: then current_user will refer to the user voting up the video and not the user who is viewing the feed... maybe this is more complicated than I had previously thought

Comment: The idea is to not update feed with entries as when user voted for his own video or it's something else?

Comment: it's something else... this is kind of confusing haha. The idea is not to update user X's feed when user Y (or any user for that matter) votes on user X's video. The main reason is because I've been using the timeline_fu plugin for an activity feed, and that would be something for a personal notifiction (since it has something do you with user X's own video). Unless instead of canceling the creation of the timeline_event object, I should just detect it somewhere in my application and render it differently... ?

Comment: I don't know the case but `I believe the right thing to do would be validating this in controller` is damned right!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because it's typically not recommended to access current_user (or session information) in your model. I am not all that familiar with the timeline_fu gem, so this answer isn't going to be the greatest answer you may get. I'm merely going to show you how to access current_user from any model.

First go to your application controller. You'll want to make a method that sets the current user. You need to call the method in the before filter.

```
before_filter :loadCurrentUser 

def loadCurrentUser
  User.currentUser = current_user
end
```

Then in your User model, you need to define 'currentUser'.

```
def self.currentUser
   Thread.currentUser[:user]
end
```

You don't necessarily have to declare the current_user in the application controller, but since it's a gem, I'm not sure if it has an easily accessible controller.

Edit: This way may be prone to problems, but I'm not entirely sure if you were asking how to make current_user available in models, or a completely different workaround so you do not have that problem... and reading the responses of the other answer, I'm thinking it's not what you were asking.

Comment: this seems like a good solution, but  it might lead to some problems if the threads are reused by container

Comment: yeah this seems like a nice solution.. I'm just afraid that this might cause unforeseen problems in my app... I think I may try it out tho